# Upgrade Next.js to 13, internalization issue raised

Tags: next.js

Why upgrading to Next.js 13 form 12 raise this error?

```
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /: /en
        /: /hu
```

I had internalisation, but no folder for [lang] before.

I did add /pages/[lang] but it also did not help.